# WCF REST JSON service caching

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, json, http

I have a WCF web service returning JSON.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Stream GetStuff(int arg);
```

And I'm using this method to convert an object graph to JSON:

```
private static Stream ToJson(object obj)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string json = serializer.Serialize(obj);

    if (WebOperationContext.Current != null)
    {
        OutgoingWebResponseContext outgoingResponse = WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;

        outgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        outgoingResponse.Headers.Add(HttpResponseHeader.CacheControl, "max-age=604800"); // one week
        outgoingResponse.LastModified = DateTime.Now;
    }

    return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json));
}
```

I'd like the responses to be cached on the browser, but the browser is still generating `If-Modified-Since` calls to the server which are replayed with `304 Not Modified`. I would like the browser to cache and use the response without making an `If-Modified-Since` call to the server each time.

I noticed that, even though I specify `Cache-Control "max-age=604800"` in the code, the response header sent by WCF is `Cache-Control    no-cache,max-age=604800`. Why is WCF adding the "no-cache" part and how do I stop it from adding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting Cache-Control to "public,max-age=...". This might prevent WCF from applying the default cache policy header.

Also, there are so called 'far future expire headers'. For heavy long-term caching I use the Expires header instead of Cache-Control:'max-age=...' and leave Cache-Control with just "public".

Comment: thank you, this solved my problem: HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(14));                HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public);

I wasn't sure HttpContext.Current is available in a WCF web service

Comment: It's available only if you run in aspNet compatibility mode.