# WP8 Improve Retrieving Data

Tags: c#, wcf, singleton, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I have a windows phone 8 application where I am getting some data in JSON format from a WCF application.

On application launch, I am performing tasks such as:

1) Is there an object saved locally, if not, get the data from WCF

2) If data retrieval is successful, save the data as an object in Isolated Storage

3) etc etc

The **problem** which I see here is that by the time the data has been retrieved from the server, the user will have reached the next page where the retrieved data should show.

This is my code:

```
public void GetSomething()
{
    var webClient = new WebClient();
    var uri = new Uri("URL Goes Here");
    webClient.OpenReadCompleted += webClient_OpenReadCompleted;
    webClient.OpenReadAsync(uri);
}

private void webClient_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(e.Result))
    {
        string data = sr.ReadToEnd();
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(data);
        var isolatedStorage = new IsolatedStorage();
        isolatedStorage.SaveSightingTypes(SightingTypes.List);

        // Store in Singleton Object
        SightingTypes.List = result.SightingTypes;
    }
```

The `webClient_OpenReadCompleted` method runs when the data is sent from the server. But as mentioned, this sometimes triggers after a good 3/4 seconds, which by then, the user will be on the page where I need the `SightingTypes.List` object.

How can I improve this?

Comment: Not much you can do on the client, but you can enable caching on the service. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278363/wcf-rest-json-service-caching